# Triangle output with formulas and user input

Tags: python-3.x

I have to write a program about triangles. I need two files, a module file and an executable file with a main method.

The module file (defines two functions):
One function that takes the three sides of a triangle as arguments. It returns True if the sides define a right triangle and false if it doesn't.

The other function must use Heron's Formula to calculate and return the area of a triangle. Learn about Heron's formula online.

The main file:
Prompt the user to enter the three sides (longest first) of the triangle. Use integers only. Make sure that no side is longer than the sum of the other two sides. Call the function that returns a boolean and use it to output whether the triangle is a right triangle, or not. Call the function that returns the area. Display the value returned with two decimal places.

I have some code I made but I am seeing that when I run it after it displays the area it says none. I have no clue where its getting that from. Also I am trying to make sure that no side is longer than the sum of the other two sides and prompt the user to re-enter the vaules. I don't know if I am using the right kind of statement as python is not recognizing it.

Here is my code:

```
def is_sum(a, b, c):
if (a > b + c) or (b > a + c) or (c > a + b):
    print ('One side is longer than the sum of the other two sides')
else:
    return True

def area(a, b, c):
s = (a + b + c) / 2

area = (s*(s-a)*(s-b)*(s-c)) **0.5
return format(area, '.2f')

def right_tri(a, b, c):
if (b**2 + c**2 == a**2):
    print('Is a right triangle')

else:
    print('Is not a right triangle')



def main () :



a = int(input('Enter longest side of the triangle'))
b = int(input('Enter the second side of the triangle'))
c = int(input('Enter the thrid side of the triangle'))


print('Area is:', area(a, b, c))
print(right_tri(a, b, c))
print(is_sum(a, b, c))

main ()
```

Answer (score 0):

Relational operators take precedence over addition, so need brackets in line 2 of is_sum
a>(b+c) etc.
Your code likely reaches the print statement all the time and the absence of a return causes the default return value None